# Single Post Template Override for Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I've got kind of a unique scenario that I'm trying to nail down. I'm working on a new template for a custom post type that already exists. Basically, we're replacing the single-customposttype.php file with a new one. All of that is going swimmingly, except one thing - they have one post in that custom post type that they want to keep the OLD template on.

So there's a NEW single-customposttype.php file that will work as the default single template for that CPT.

But I need ID #93 to use the OLD single-customposttype.php template. I hoped just doing single-customposttype-93.php might do the trick, but it doesn't. What's the best way to apply the other template to only one post id?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I deal with custom template loading **all the time**, it's really pretty simple! Really, all you need to do is hook into the [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) hook, and override the template based on whatever conditions you want.

That hook takes a single argument, the `$template` file to load. You can then use any conditionals you want and force a separate file to load instead.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_template_include', 99 );
function custom_template_include( $template ){
    // For ID 93, load in file by using it's PATH (not URL)
    if( get_the_ID() === 93 ){
        // Note the file name can be ANYTHING, the WP auto-template names don't matter here
        $file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/post-id-93-custom-template.php';

        // It's generally good to see if the file exists before overriding the default
        if( file_exists( $file ) )
            $template = $file;
    }

    // ALWAYS return the $template, or *everything* will be blank.
    return $template;
}
```

It's really that simple! Inside the custom PHP file, you have access to all of the WordPress functions and such as you would with a default template.

Generally you'll want to use the `file_exists()` function on the template, just to make sure it's found, otherwise you'll be passing along a file that doesn't exist, and that page will not load. By checking if it exists, it will still fall back to the old template if it's not found (deleted/renamed/moved, etc)

Also, you **always** need to have `return $template` at the end, otherwise anything that uses WordPress' template system will break.

---

I made a quick example on a demo site:

- https://xhynk.com/content-mask/policies/cookie-policy/
- https://xhynk.com/content-mask/policies/use-another-template/

The policies are a custom post type, and the cookie policy loads normally. The other one is modified with the same code as above (with the name/ID changed to match), and it's loading in a simple .php file with that content in it.

Comment: Hmm. It seems so straightforward, and your example obviously works. But for some reason, it doesn't work on my installation. The only thing I changed from your code was the file name, and it does indeed exist. Leads me to believe something in my install is perhaps overriding the override. Any ideas? (Sorry, I can't show the install due to NDA)

Comment: Is the file in the right place? The code above assumes it's in base level of the theme directory. You can do `var_dump(file_exists($file));` and it will spit out `bool(true)` if everything is good. If it is, you can try changing the priority of the function from `99` to something higher, `999` or `9999` - there may be something in the theme or a plugin that's running something on `template_include` at a later point than `99`